# Fullcalendar: on 'dayClick' pop-up IF an event exists

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The way I'm trying to make this work is the idea of "blocking a day" to unavailable and available. How can I make the whole day's block clickable even if there is an event on it?

If there currently is an event on a day I want to block, I'd like to see that event in a pop-up.

One of the issues is that currently only way to activate "dayClick" is if you click on an empty area. But if you click on an event it will not trigger "dayClick". Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that dayClick needs is not available when you click on an event (eventClick).  I don't know of a way to drill through the event to get to dayClick. i.e., I can't think of a way to call $.trigger to call dayClick.

You should be able to do what you need in the eventClick callback.  When creating individual events, set a property to available or unavailable.  Maybe something like this:

```
var events = [{
                 id: 1,
                 title: 'This is a blocked day',
                 start: 'Wed, 18 Oct 2009 08:00:00 EST',
                 color:'#fff',// red
                 blocked: true
             },
             {
                 id: 2,
                 title: 'This is an available day',
                 start: 'Thu, 19 Oct 2009 08:00:00 EST',
                 color: '#07A800', // green
                 blocked: false
             }];

$('#cal').fullcalendar({
    events: events,
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        if(calEvent.blocked == true) {// be sure to set a 'blocked' property in your event
            alert('This time is not available!');                
        } else {
            $('#newEventDialog').dialog('open');// open a dialog to save new event
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well essentially what i want to do by "blocking" a day, to gray it out. So no events can be created for that day. And IF there are events already in a day, to spit out the the events in a list. And from that if you still want to block the day, you can do it from this list/pop-up.

Comment: the api does not provide a method to 'gray out' a specific day.  And you will have to use the eventClick and dayClick callbacks to grammatically control the behavior.  You might need to do two sets of events.  One set that is your actual events and another set that you use to occupy space for 'grayed out' days.